# Creating a comma separated vector

Tags: r

I have a numeric vector, one, which I'm trying to turn into a character vector where 
each element is separated by commas.

```
> one = c(1:5)
> paste(as.character(one), collapse=", ")
[1] "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
> paste(as.character(one), sep="' '", collapse=", ")
[1] "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

However, I want the output to look like:

```
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
```

Am I missing some parameter from the paste function?
Help!?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`shQuote` is probably the best way to do this. Specifically, this gets you the output you want:

```
cat(paste(shQuote(one, type="cmd"), collapse=", "))
```

If single quotes are fine, you can use:

```
paste(shQuote(one), collapse=", ")
```

`type="cmd"` actually provides escaped quotes, which is what's actually useful for most contexts, but if you really want to display it somewhere with unescaped quotes, `cat` provides that.

Comment: `paste(shQuote(one), collapse=", ")` gives `[1] "\"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\""`, not single quote enclosed variant.

Answer (score 56):

You say you want a character vector with that output, but others who find this question may be looking for one of these functions instead:

First, a way to get output ready for input to R; that would be `dput`:

```
> dput(as.character(one))
c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
```

Second, a way to output a csv file, which would be `write.csv` or `write.table`.  These functions take a parameter `file`, not used here, to directly output to a file.

```
> write.table(matrix(as.character(one),nrow=1), sep=",",
              row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
"1","2","3","4","5"

> write.csv(matrix(as.character(one),nrow=1),row.names=FALSE)
"V1","V2","V3","V4","V5"
"1","2","3","4","5"
```

Comment: This is the best answer; it works for numeric vectors too if you exclude the `as.character` function

Answer (score 20):

Assuming you want your output in a character string (as opposed to a vector of characters) you could try:

```
paste("'",as.character(one),"'",collapse=", ",sep="")
```

That gives you single quotes around the numbers rather than double quotes, but it's basically what you seem to want.

And you can always escape to get double quotes:

```
rs <- paste("\"",as.character(one),"\"",collapse=", ",sep="")
cat(rs)
```

that should print out what you want with the double quotes.

Answer (score 5):

Something similar with toString

```
toString(paste0("'",1:10,"'") )
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to `shQuote`, see the functions `sQuote` and `dQuote` to wrap text in single and double quotes respectively. You'll also want to set `options(useFancyQuotes=FALSE)` to get plain (unidirectional) ASCII quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add on to Noah's answer if you want to use the `paste` function:

```
paste(shQuote(one, type="sh"), collapse=", ")
```

Should give you:

```
[1] '1','2','3','4','5'
```

Answer (score -2):

```
paste("'",as.character(one),"'",collapse=", ",sep="")
```

gives me:

> [1] "'stop_id', 'stop_code', 'stop_name', 'stop_desc', 'stop_lat',
> 'stop_lon', 'location_type', 'parent_station'"

```
paste(",",as.character(one),"",collapse=" ",sep=" ")

cat(one,sep=",")
```

gives me:

> ", stop_id  , stop_code  , stop_name  , stop_desc  , stop_lat  ,
> stop_lon  , location_type  , parent_station "

```
cat(one,sep=",")
```

gives me:

> stop_id,stop_code,stop_name,stop_desc,stop_lat,stop_lon,location_type,parent_station