# Insert comma between characters with R

Tags: r

Sample data:

```
data <- round(rnorm(10,100000,10000),-1)
char <- as.character(data)
```

and I would like comma between the characters:

```
[1] "104350","108800","101320","94140","102260","89340","114220","105830","111270","85300"
```

I have tried `paste()` and also `read.table` & `read.lines` with `sep=","` with no success.

Comment: Is this what you're after `cat(paste0('"', paste(char, collapse="\", \""), '"'))`?

Comment: That's it!I spent hours playing around!If you post it as answer I'm ready to accept.

Comment: It looks like you are asking to change how R displays a vector of strings, which is slightly different from creating a string that contains the numbers separated by a column. If you're looking for the latter then @rbatt provided a good answer. Otherwise, assuming your goal is not completely cosmetic, it would be informative to know your ultimate goal.

Comment: its going into automated scraping function. The function requires this form as the function takes 1 string at a time. The strings are just the missing part of url... as always there may be workaround but this works for me.

Comment: @Max, is that an R function?  The form is unusual.

Comment: Related question: "Creating a comma-separated vector" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347356/creating-a-comma-separated-vector?rq=1

Comment: This `sink` function could work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're after the aesthetic not the functional with this answer:

```
cat(paste0('"', paste(char, collapse="\", \""), '"'))

## "115030", "118990", "72910", "121050", "93820", "119310", "110370", "100590", "98220", "118200"
```

To store:

```
store <- paste0('"', paste(char, collapse="\", \""), '"')
```

Comment: However I would need to store the output :), I have tried with `capture.output()` but that put's backticks/back quotes.

Comment: I think you need to tell us what you aim to do with this string, why you want it like this so we can guide appropriately.

Comment: You can save it as `x <- paste0('"', paste(char, collapse="\", \""), '"'); save.image('x')`.  Then next time you open R, `load('x')`

Answer (score 0):

The `sink` function can be used to force the text output.

```
sink('output.txt')

cat(paste0('"', paste(char, collapse="\", \""), '"'))

sink()
```