# R how to collapse the vector of character strings without losing the " " at the beginning and end of each word

Tags: r, list, vector

I want to get the line up data from this site; http://festileaks.com/pinkpop-festival/pinkpop-programma-2015/  , as input for a function.

To use the data for my function I need it to be in a list. For this to work all the artists need to be between " " , which is the case in the vector of character strings. As soon as I collapse the vector into one string the "artist" changes into artist (without " "). Is there a way to get the artists into one list and not lose the " " ?

This is the code I use (Rpackage rvest);

```
Pinkpop_2015 <- read_html("http://festileaks.com/pinkpop-festival/pinkpop-          programma-2015/")
Pinkpophtml <- html_nodes(Pinkpop_2015, ".g7-one_third > a")
Pinkpoplineup <- html_text(Pinkpophtml)
Pinkpoplineup <- gsub("Â", "", Pinkpoplineup)
Pinkpoplineup <- gsub("-", "", Pinkpoplineup)
Pinkpoplineup <- gsub("^ ", '', Pinkpoplineup)

Plineup_string = paste(Pinkpoplineup, collapse=" ,")
```

Comment: Can you show what you want the result to look like vs. what you are getting currently?

Comment: Try using shQuote, as described here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347356/creating-a-comma-separated-vector

Comment: like this?? `Plineup_string = paste0('\"', Pinkpoplineup, '\"', collapse=", ")`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this puts a \" in front and a /" at the back of all the text.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. so based on your new character vector (I took just the first three occurrences):

```
Pinkpoplineup <- "Vrijdag 12 juni\n Muse\n Elbow"
```

You can try

```
Pinkpoplineup <- unlist(strsplit(Pinkpoplineup, split="\n "))

Pinkpoplineup  <- paste0('\"', Pinkpoplineup, '\"', collapse=",")
```

Quotes are now escaped and you can see the result using

```
cat(Pinkpoplineup)
```

or writing the object to a file

```
write(Pinkpoplineup, file = "Pinkpoplineup.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this puts a \" in front and a /" at the back of all the text.

Comment: Mmmm. not sure what is going on. Now I get an empty list after running your code (`library(rvest)` is loaded) . Has something changed?? If you get to any valid result, can you share an example of the object `Pinkpoplineup `?  you can share it typing `dput(Pinkpoplineup)` and copy -past it here.

Comment: "Vrijdag 12 juni\n Muse\n Elbow\n Slash ft. Myles Kennedy & The Conspirators\n George Ezra\n Faith No More\n Above & Beyond\n Paloma Faith\n Gavin James \n DJ's Waxfriend & Prime ft. JeBroer & Adje\n Pop Evil\n Jick Munro & The Amazing Laserbeams\n Shaka Ponk\n  Aurora\n  Coasts\n Body Count feat. IceT\n Anna Rune"