# How to create a comma separated vector and save it in a text file in R?

Tags: r, output, saving-data

I found a reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347356/creating-a-comma-separated-vector). But I want to seek something more. I want to save it in a text file. Now, suppose the vector is very large. Then, it is not possible to see it on the console and copy-paste it. Can you guys provide me some insight?

I tried with `cat`and `shQuote`. But I want to save them in the following format.

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
.............................,
.............................,
9991,9992,...............,10000
```

If it can be shown in the format, it would be best (i.e comma separated and in different rows as well). But it is in a single row, that will also work. Please help !

Comment: working example please

Comment: Maybe `write.csv(matrix(x, ncol = 10), "myFile.csv")` ?

Comment: I don't want it in `csv` format. Even though, this is not working.

Comment: To get rid of column names, use `write.table` with `sep = ','`, e.g. `write.table(matrix(1:100, ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE), 'test.csv', row.names = F, col.names = F, sep = ',')`

Answer (score 3):

```
 vect = c(1:5)
vectStr=paste(as.character(vect), sep="' '", collapse=",")
sink("outfile.txt")
cat(vectStr)
cat("\n")
sink()
```

`sink` is useful to write on file

Now , check with :

```
file.show("outfile.txt")
 # 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: But there is no file creating named as "outfile.txt" in the directory

Answer (score 1):

Just use `write` once you get your string in the right format:

```
write(paste(1:20, collapse = ','), 'test.txt')
```

Really, a CSV is probably more useful, though, e.g.

```
write.csv(1:20, 'test.csv')
```

Comment: @SoutikRivuGhosal How is this solution going to look like when the vector is 1:10000? It will be a file with just one row.

Comment: Actually, when I used the `write(paste(1:10000, collapse = ','), 'test.txt')`, I found that it `test.txt` is created in the directory with multiple rows.

Comment: @SoutikRivuGhosal **No**, it creates only one row, probably the editor is wrapping one row to multiple rows. Try this `nrow(read.table("test.txt"))`.

Comment: @SoutikRivuGhosal, @zx8754 is right; if you pass this a single string, you'll get a single row. While that's horrible for human reading, it may be ok for your computer, but there's a reason you're getting so many recommendations to do something else. To get slightly (though not wholly) better, you can just leave the vector as multiple strings, which will save on multiple lines: `write(tapply(1:100, ceiling((1:100)/10), paste, collapse = ','), 'test.txt')`, which is equivalent to `write.table(matrix(1:100, ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE), 'test.csv', row.names = F, col.names = F, sep = ',')`.

Comment: @zx8754, yes I discovered that later. Thanks. I just wanted to copy it. Because R console just shows part of the row and hence impossible to copy. But for a text file that does not matter.

Comment: If you're just trying to copy it, you can send it to the clipboard directly instead of writing to a file first, though how to do so differs by OS. [The `clipr` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clipr/index.html) offers a nice platform-independent alternative to the base options, if you prefer.