# creating string of numbers seperated by commas

Tags: r

I am trying to create a comma separated string exactly like this to put in a url: `1,2,3,4,5` but when I try: `paste0(1:5,sep=",")` it returns: `[1] "1,"  "2,"  "3,"  "4,"  "5,"` The spaces are causing issues. How do I get rid of them?

This is not the same question as: [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347356/creating-a-comma-separated-vector) the solution is almost the same, but the question approaches it from a different angle. My question is trying to suppress the spaces, the linked question wants them.

Comment: @Frank and to all the others who have voted to close: Using a wrong parameter is *not* a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `collapse=","` instead of `sep=","`:

```
paste0(1:5,collapse=",")
[1] "1,2,3,4,5"
```

Comment: .....cant believe I didnt think of that

Comment: @Rilcon42 Such things happen, don't worry. One of the comments has been edited and corrected, too.