# R - cat function does not work/always return NULL in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

This might be a quite silly question.
But I have wrapped my head around this for a morning but had no avail.

Basically, I get user input from multiple select input, let's say user inputs are:

`"apple" "banana" "pineapple"`

I need to fetch data from db according to the user inputs, like a `where f.name in (xxx)`, so I need to transform the user inputs into

`"apple","banana","pineapple"`

I've referenced [Comma separated vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347356/creating-a-comma-separated-vector), and this works quite fine in the `Console` panel, but back to Shiny, the result is always `NULL`.(what interesting is, if I type `cat(pasteM)` in the console, it is correct!!!!)

I don't know what's the difference between Shiny and the Console. Why does the Shiny always return `NULL`?

```
quoteM <- shQuote(as.vector(input$fruits), type="cmd")
pasteM <- paste(quoteM, collapse=", ") # pasteM has value
resultM <- cat(pasteM) # resultM is always NULL
```

Comment: `cat` only returns `(invisible) NULL`, as documented in its help file.

Comment: It looks like you already have the character vector produced by `paste(quoteM, collapse=", ")`. Can't you use that?

Comment: No, pasteM returns things like this `"\"apple\", \"banana\", \"pineapple\""`, I need to remove the escape character

Answer (score 0):

`cat(pasteM)` prints the result for you in the console because that is literally what `cat()` is doing: to **concatenate and print**. I'm guessing why it didn't work for you in Shiny is because the variable was not created in the environment that Shiny is evaluated in. To prove this, I would suggest you change the assignment operator to `<<-` and see if it is in fact due to the scoping environment. Your code should look like this:

```
quoteM <- shQuote(as.vector(input$fruits), type="cmd")
pasteM <- paste(quoteM, collapse=", ") # pasteM has value
resultM <<- cat(pasteM) # resultM is always NULL
```

The alternative is to `return(resultM)` from the enclosing function, so Shiny can interact with that variable.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I have tried both of your solution. Unfortunately, resultM is always NULL.