# Using IN Operator for Google BigQuery in R

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I'm passing a vector of web pages, read from an XLSX file, to a SQL statement to be used in BigQuery but am coming up with an error when using the IN operator.

```
library(xlsx)
library(dplyr)
library(bigrquery)

test_control_group <- xlsx::read.xlsx('./test_control_group.xlsx',
                                      sheetName = 'Test_Control')

pages <- test_control_group %>%
  dplyr::select(page) %>%
  distinct()

projectid <- "googleproject"

sql <- paste0(
  "SELECT * FROM `googleproject.dataset.table`
       WHERE page IN (", pages, ")"
)

tb <- bigrquery::bq_project_query(projectid, sql)
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Job 'googleproject.job_bheGLdlR4_WqQ4iMu2G8UcFNscEc.europe-west2' failed
x Function not found: c at [5:24] [invalidQuery]
```

Since it is recognising R's c() notation.

```
"\n SELECT * FROM `googleproject.dataset.table`\n  WHERE page IN (c(\"https:...))"
```

How do I get around this problem please?

Comment: What is the value of `pages` ?

Comment: Consider the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347356/creating-a-comma-separated-vector

Comment: Thanks @rtenha, dput worked with a regex replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following lines to the code worked.

```
pages <- dput(as.character(pages))
pages <- str_replace_all(pages, "(c\\(|\\))","")
```

So the script now looks like:

```
library(xlsx)
library(dplyr)
library(bigrquery)

test_control_group <- xlsx::read.xlsx('./test_control_group.xlsx',
                                      sheetName = 'Test_Control')

pages <- test_control_group %>%
  dplyr::select(page) %>%
  distinct()
pages <- dput(as.character(pages))
pages <- str_replace_all(pages, "(c\\(|\\))","")


projectid <- "googleproject"

sql <- paste0(
  "SELECT * FROM `googleproject.dataset.table`
       WHERE page IN (", pages, ")"
)

tb <- bigrquery::bq_project_query(projectid, sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

here I suggest you check these options.

The variable pages save in a variable to get the results in this variable and this new variable concatenate in the SQL query . You can see more [information about c Function](https://statisticsglobe.com/c-function-in-r)

You can see this example.

```
#Save the c function to a variable
x2 <- c(\"https:...”)
 
#use in the query statement
sql <- paste0( "SELECT * FROM `googleproject.dataset.table` WHERE page IN (", x2, ")" )
```

You can use the unnest statement with BigQuery and isnet the data in a new table and manipulate all the information in BigQuery. You can see more information about the [UNNEST statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays).

You can see this example.

```
SELECT *
FROM UNNEST(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'corge', 'garply', 'waldo', 'fred'])
  AS element
WITH OFFSET AS offset
ORDER BY offset;

+----------+--------+
| element  | offset |
+----------+--------+
| foo      | 0      |
| bar      | 1      |
| baz      | 2      |
| qux      | 3      |
| corge    | 4      |
| garply   | 5      |
| waldo    | 6      |
| fred     | 7      |
+----------+--------+
```

Maybe you could insert the data from the excel to BigQuery in another table and manipulate all the information from the database. You can see more [information about export to BigQuery](https://hevodata.com/learn/excel-to-bigquery/).